# TypeError: E is not a function Vite.js React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, typeerror, vite

I'm facing the following problem. After building the project and starting production server I got TypeError: E is not a function[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRL0t.png)

The problem is on desktop version only, so I thought it could be something with useMediaQuery hook from react-responsive and removed it's usage from project. The error is not thrown now, but I still need to use useMediaQuery. What can be the problem with this hook and how can I solve it?

Here's an example of useMediaQuery usage

```
import React from 'react'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive'

export const TrustBlock = (): JSX.Element => {
    const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 650px)' })
    const isTablet = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 1200px)' })
    return (
        <div className='container'>
                <Swiper spaceBetween={20} slidesPerView={isMobile ? 1 : isTablet ? 3 : 4} navigation loop>
                    
                </Swiper>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, can you copy & paste your error message into the question itself? This will make it easier for people to find this question, and makes it more likely someone will answer it.

Comment: It might also help if you show the snippet of code where you use `useMediaQuery`

Comment: @Dakeyras added a snippet

Comment: Known bug but currently unsolved: https://github.com/yocontra/react-responsive/issues/306